# Will it work? From Intel Core i5-2430M to Intel Core i7-3610QE?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a question. I have an old Sony Vaio laptop (VPCEJ2Z1E) with an i5-2430M processor. The chipset is a HM65 motherboard.

I had looked at the compatibility of HM65 boards on the [CPU Upgrade](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com) website and looked out for the i7-3610QE in terms of price-performance.

But if I go to the i5-2430M, the i7-3610QE is not displayed. Also, the i5 stands for Sandy Bridge while the i7 stands for Ivy Bridge.

So will the change work out or should I rather look through a different construction?

Comment: While the chipset is one part of the compatibility question, the socket is another, and the BIOS is yet another. You need to check the upgrade compatibility of these other parts of the system to see whether this is a viable upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

The
[CPU-Upgrade website](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/)
in its page for the
[Intel HM65 Express chipset processor support](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/HM65_Express.html)
contains this:

> [i7-3610QE](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_i7_Mobile/i7-3610QE.html) - AW8063801118306
> i7-3610QE, L3 6 MB, Turbo 3.3 GHz

So it seems that this CPU is supported for your motherboard.

However, I would suggest not to take this information as more than
a positive indication.
I would suggest to buy the CPU from a vendor that has a no-question
return policy.